# Joomla SQL Query error after Componant install

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla3.0

I recently installed arra user migrate and now when i go to Manage under extensions (i want to remove it) i get a server error:

```
Unknown column 'a.id' in 'where clause' SQL=SELECT COUNT(*) FROM n3dmx_extensions WHERE state=0 AND a.id != 1013 AND a.id != 1014 AND a.id != 1015 Unknown column 'a.id' in 'where clause' SQL=SELECT *,2*protected+(1-protected)*enabled as status FROM n3dmx_extensions WHERE state=0 AND a.id != 1013 AND a.id != 1014 AND a.id != 1015 Unknown column 'a.id' in 'where clause' SQL=SELECT COUNT(*) FROM n3dmx_extensions WHERE state=0 AND a.id != 1013 AND a.id != 1014 AND a.id != 1015
```

Im not sure where to go from here as this was working ok previously, ideally i don't want to have to restore from a back up. Any advice on how to fix it? I have already clicked 'Fix Database' and updated to the latest version of joomla? Where are the SQL queries stored/created?

Best Regards
Donna

Comment: What is "arra user migrate"? Are you getting the message as soon as you go to manage or when you try to uninstall?

Comment: Check your database. You are missing table `n3dmx_extensions `.

Comment: Arra User Migrate is a Joomla component, the n3dmx_extensions table is present, its the alias a.id that isn't defined and im not sure how to modify the query as i do not know what and how it is generated.

Answer (score 1):

Found this while looking for a solution for the same issue. It seems like this issue is a result of a hack attack. It inserts something similar to below code into the `getItems()` function of `/libraries/legacy/model/list.php` file.

```
$query->where('a.id != 1015');
```

The number `1015` might be different in each case. Mine was `9417`.

More details at [this forum post](http://fabrikar.com/forums/index.php?threads/error-500-unknown-column.43439/#post-222246).

Removing the above code with get your site back to normal. But obviously this is a result of hack attack. This tells you that you need pay more attention to the security of your Joomla site.